# Answered: Selecting even table rows from a table element

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

The issue I am having is:

How do I go from a variable pointing at a dom element to using CSS selectors?

I want to make this work:

```
function highlight(table)
{$(table " > :even").toggleClass('highlight');}
```

where table is a reference to a table element.

I don't want answers that tell me to use $('#table') because that defeats the point of the generality I am trying to make.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
function highlight(table) {
  $(table).find("tr:even").toggleClass('highlight');
}
```

Alternatively you can use `'> :even'`, but be careful because there are `<tbody>` elements and such to deal with here, unless you have nested tables, the code above is a more resilient approach.

Comment: @patrick - Depends how you interpret "a variable pointing at an element", I agree it's not completely clear. I take that to mean a DOM element...hopefully the OP will clarify this for us, you may be right, just depends what he meant.

Comment: Good point. I think I'll just give a disclaimer in mine, but I've got the feeling it is a reference to an actual element.

Comment: Right, I listed ('#table') in the initial description to clarify that.  I changed the language a bit too now.  Is it clearer?

Answer (score 1):

Concatenation.

```
$(table + " > :even")
```

---

**DISCLAIMER:**

This will only work if the `table` variable is referencing a String that describes the element. If the variable is actually referencing a DOM element, you would either need to pull the ID out of it before you concatenate, or (better) see **Nick Craver's** answer.

Comment: thanks! thats very succinct and readable for jquery developers, if it works, ill try it out

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a second argument to `$()` which indicates the context the search should run in:

```
$("tr:even", table)
```